# php date format unusual

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to format a timestamp coming from a mysql table, stored as a string.

It is in this format: 16/08/16 4:41 PM EDT

When I try date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp), I get a non well formed error.

Comment: Is your data a timestamp or a string? The `date` function expects a timestamp for the second parameter, which could be why you're getting an error.  As a side note, MySQL has several data types for storing dates/times to help you avoid storing them as strings.

Comment: Use `strtotime()` dd/mm/yy is a European format that `strtotime()` uses `-` not `/`.  Replace `/` to `-`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This format `16/08/16 4:41 PM EDT` is not a timestamp format. A timestamp is a integer like `1471385740`.

For these conversions I use [Zend_Date](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.date.constants.html):

```
$format = "yy-MM-dd hh:MM:ss a zzz"
$date = new Zend_Date($format, "16/08/16 4:41 PM EDT");
echo $date->get('yyyy-MM-dd'); // desired format
```